# How to call a templated function for each type in a tuple (acting as type list) with tuple b as argument

Tags: c++, tuples, c++20, constexpr

How to call a template function for each type in a typelist with arguments (e.g. another tuple)?

Given is a typelist `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3, ...>` and a `std::tuple` containing data.

```
template <typename T>
void doSomething (const auto& arg) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

template <typename T> struct w {T v; w(T _v) : v{_v} {}};

int main () {
    using types = std::tuple<int, char, float, double, w<int>, w<float>>; // used as type list
    constexpr auto data = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0, 4.0f, w(5.0));
    // call doSomething<T>(data) for each type in types
    // like
    // someFunctor<types>(doSomething, data);
}
```

My current idea is a functor like appreach that receives the typelist to extract nexted types and `std::tuple<Ts>` having an `operator ()` to call `doSomething<T>(args)` for each of Ts.

```
template<template<typename...> typename TL, typename... Ts>
struct someFunctor {
    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr void operator() (Args&&... args) {
        (doSomething<Ts>(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...);
    }
};
```

Not sure if that's the smartest approach. Brain fog blocked me so far to get it work.

Comment: Why is the tuple of types different from the type of the tuple of values? It even has different length in your example. What should happen if the types of an element don't coincide? In other words, why do you want `someFunctor<types>(doSomething, data);` instead of `someFunctor(doSomething, data);`?

Comment: Is `const auto &` in `doSomething` intended, or was it supposed to be `const T &`?

Comment: @user17732522 types and data are independent of each other. The to be called function will do different things with data, depending on each type of types.

Comment: @ChrisG. I am still not sure what should happen. Do you want `doSomething` to be called for each type in `types` once with `arg` being a reference to `data` each time?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this is intended. It needs each T + the argument(s) like ```doSomething<int>(data); doSomething<char>(data); doSomething<w<int>>(data); ...```

Comment: @user17732522 yes, indeed! Passing a functor/lambda instead might do it.

Comment: @ChrisG. Nevermind, for some reason I forgot that you can call `operator()` explicitly with template arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use template partial specialization to extract the type of typelist, then use fold-expression to invoke `doSomething` with different template parameters

```
template<typename Tuple>
struct someFunctor;

template<typename... Args>
struct someFunctor<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  template<class T>
  constexpr void operator()(T&& x) {
    (doSomething<Args>(std::forward<T>(x)), ...);
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fr4Ts5d9j)

```
using types = std::tuple<int, char, float, double, w<int>, w<float>>;
constexpr auto data = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0, 4.0f, w(5.0f));
someFunctor<types>()(data);
```

Comment: That looks pretty nice 康桓瑋! Is there a way to make use of a template template argument to avoid specializations for different type containers than ```std::tuple```? Indeed the type comparison is over the top as @user17732522 mentioned, but handy now that I see it.

Comment: @ChrisG. `template<template<typename...> class TL, typename... Args> struct someFunctor<TL<Args...>> {`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short piece of code to do it:

```cpp
using types = std::tuple<int, char, float, double, w<int>, w<float>>;
constexpr auto data = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3.0, 4.0f, w(5.0));
[&]<template<typename...> class TL, typename... Ts>(TL<Ts...>*) {
    // Now have a parameter pack of `Ts`
    (doSomething<Ts>(data), ...);
}((types*) nullptr);
```

And turned into a reusable function, you can do something like:

```cpp
template<typename types, typename Functor, typename... Args>
constexpr void mapTypeList(Functor&& f, Args&&... args) {
    [&]<template<typename...> class TL, typename... Ts>(TL<Ts...>*) {
        ((void) f.template operator()<Ts>(std::forward<Args>(args)...), ...);
    }(static_cast<types*>(nullptr));
}


// You need to wrap `doSomething` in a lambda
mapTypeList<types>([]<typename T>(const auto& data) { doSomething<T>(data); }, data);
// or maybe capturing data:
mapTypeList<types>([&]<typename T>() { doSomething<T>(data); });
```

Example usage: https://godbolt.org/z/53x44bGvK